# UWP query about stack panel and treeview

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to add stack panel inside treeview in UWP ?

If yes please share syntax for same.

```
<muxc:TreeView> 
    <muxc:TreeView.RootNodes> 
        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Flavors" IsExpanded="True"> 
            <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children> 
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Vanilla"/> 
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Strawberry"/> 
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Chocolate"/> 
            </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children> 
        </muxc:TreeViewNode> 
    </muxc:TreeView.RootNodes> 
</muxc:TreeView>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide code samples of what you have tried already.

Comment: <muxc:TreeView> <muxc:TreeView.RootNodes> <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Flavors" IsExpanded="True"> <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children> <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Vanilla"/> <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Strawberry"/> <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Chocolate"/> </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children> </muxc:TreeViewNode> </muxc:TreeView.RootNodes> </muxc:TreeView>.       This is how my code looks like. I want to add stack panel when I click on Flavors. Any luck ?

Answer (score 0):

A `TreeViewItem` has a `Content` property that you can set to a `StackPanel`:

```
<TreeViewItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="..." />
    </StackPanel>
</TreeViewItem>
```

You'll find a complete example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
        <muxc:TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Source="Assets/folder.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </muxc:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
        <muxc:TreeViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Source="Assets/file.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </muxc:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ExplorerItemTemplateSelector
            x:Key="ExplorerItemTemplateSelector"
            FolderTemplate="{StaticResource FolderTemplate}"
            FileTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <muxc:TreeView
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind DataSource}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerItemTemplateSelector}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: When I tried above code its throwing another error. The debugger stops here "if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();"

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly add stack panel in TreeView.The better way is to use ItemTemplateSelector.You can prepare for two item template:only stackPanel template and normal template.When you click on Flavors,you can add stackPanel template in TreeView.

.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StackPanelItemDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
        <muxc:TreeViewItem >
            <StackPanel Height="100" Orientation="Vertical">
            </StackPanel>
        </muxc:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
        <muxc:TreeViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Height="44"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </muxc:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FolderDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
        <muxc:TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}">
            <StackPanel Height="44" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </muxc:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ExplorerItemTemplateSelector
    x:Key="ExplorerItemTemplateSelector"
    StackPanelItemDataTemplate="{StaticResource StackPanelItemDataTemplate}"
    FolderDataTemplate="{StaticResource FolderDataTemplate}"
    NormalItemDataTemplate="{StaticResource NormalItemDataTemplate}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <muxc:TreeView x:Name="sampleTreeView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DataSource}"
               ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerItemTemplateSelector}"
               ItemInvoked="TreeView_ItemInvoked"/>
</Grid>
```

.cs:

Create a viewmodel to bind with the control and use NameType to distinguish which template to use.

```
public class ExplorerItem
{ 
    public String NameType;
    public String Name;
    public ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem> Children = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem>();
}

public class ExplorerItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FolderDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate NormalItemDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate StackPanelItemDataTemplate { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        var explorerItem = (ExplorerItem)item;
        if (explorerItem.NameType == "Folder")
        {
            return FolderDataTemplate;
        }else if (explorerItem.NameType == "StackPanel")
        {
            return StackPanelItemDataTemplate;
        }else
        {
            return NormalItemDataTemplate;
        }
    }
 }
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem> DataSource = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ExplorerItem flavorsCategory = new ExplorerItem()
        {
            Name = "Flavors",
            NameType = "Folder",
            Children =
            {
                new ExplorerItem() { Name = "Vanilla" },
                new ExplorerItem() { Name = "Strawberry"},
                new ExplorerItem() { Name = "Chocolate" }
            }
        };

        DataSource .Add(flavorsCategory);
    }
}
```

When you want to add StackPanel:

```
private void TreeView_ItemInvoked(TreeView sender, TreeViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    ExplorerItem clickItem = args.InvokedItem as ExplorerItem;
    if (clickItem.Name == "Flavors") {
        ExplorerItem i = DataSource[0];
        ExplorerItem item = new ExplorerItem() { Name = "Vanilla", NameType = "StackPanel" };
        i.Children.Insert(0, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried above code its throwing another error.

The debugger stops here "if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();"

Comment: Also please let me know where the below code to be added.

"ExplorerItem i = DataSource[0];
ExplorerItem item = new ExplorerItem() { Name = "Vanilla", NameType = "StackPanel" };
i.Children.Insert(0,item);"

Comment: When I used above code,I didn't receive the error.Did you change something when you used?When you click the Flavors item,you can add StatckPanel.I subscribe the ItemClick event and implement it.Then add the code in the method.I have updated my answer,you can try it.